# Python and very small decimals

Tags: python, floating-point

Interesting fact on Python 2.7.6 running on macosx:

You have a very small number like:

```
0.000000000000000000001
```

You can represent it as:

```
>>> 0.1 / (10 ** 20)
1.0000000000000001e-21
```

But you can see the floating pointing error at the end. What we *really* have is something like this:

```
0.0000000000000000000010000000000000001
```

So we got an error in the number, but thats ok. The problem is the following:

As expected:

```
>>> 0.1 / (10 ** 20) == 0
False
```

But, wait, whats this?

```
>>> 0.1 / (10 ** 20) + 1 == 1
True

>>> repr(0.1 / (10 ** 20) + 1)
'1.0'
```

Looks like python is using another data type to represent my number as this only happens when using the 16th decimal digit and so on. Also why python decided to automatically turn my number to `0` on the addition? Should not I be dealing with a decimal number with a very small decimal part and with a floating point error?

I know this problem can fall in the *floating point errors* umbrella, and the solution normally is do not trust floating point for this kinda of calculation, but I would like to understand more about whats happening under the hood.

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html - it's a very popular paper on floating-point arithmethic.

Comment: You might also look at the `Decimal` module which allows you to specify precision.

Comment: A more approachable introduction to floating-point is https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Weaknesses/ . Scroll down to “Adding Large and Small Numbers”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating point numbers work like scientific notation. `1.0000000000000001e-21` fits within the **53 bits of significand/mantissa** a 64-bit float allows. Adding `1` to that, many orders of magnitude larger than the tiny fraction, causes the minor detail to be discarded, and storing exactly `1` instead

Comment: Python floats are actually doubles, so you get 53 bits of precision. But the same applies.

Comment: Oh dang I totally knew that, thanks for correcting me. Updating answer

Comment: Indeed, thats interesting. `1e-21` is indeed possible to represent on a floating point, but `1 + 1e-21` would result in `1.000000000000000000001e-0`. Its tricky how adding `1` to `1e-21` looks simple, but is somewhat like mixing elephants with atoms

Comment: Elephants and atoms. I like that.

Answer (score 8):

Consider what happens when you attempt to add 7.00 and .001 and are only permitted to use three digits for the answer. 7.001 is not allowed. What do you do?

Of the values you can return, such as 6.99, 7.00, and 7.01, the closest to the correct answer is 7.00. So, when asked to add 7.00 and .001, you return 7.00.

The computer has the same issue when you ask it to add a number near 1e-21 and 1. It has only 53 bits to use for the fraction portion of the floating-point value, and 1e-21 is almost 70 bits below 1. So, it rounds the correct result to the closest value it can, 1, and returns that.

Comment: Thats a nice answer, but it would be more complete if it explained why then i can have indeed the `1e-21` number at all, but not `1 + 1e-21` number. Following your explanation, `1e-21` would be rounded to `0` even before the addition, but thats not the case. I think the key here is pointing out that is indeed possible to represent `1e-21` in a floating point using scientific notation, but not `1 + 1e-21` as it would result in `1.000000000000000000001e-0` in scientific notation

Comment: I have a scenario where I need to retain the detail - is there a way to do this?